# Resize imageview's height and width using auto layout (IOS)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview, ios-autolayout

I have an image view and a text label inside of my cell view. 
Trying to create a speech bubble like you can see in most chat applications.

The problem is that I want to do it using auto layout.

My text field resizes in width and height correctly.

But when I set my image view to equal width of the text field, the text field no longer resizes in width according to the text and as a result, they're both not the correct width.

Anyone have any idea how I can do this?

[Storyboard screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEFMi.png)

Comment: Please, show your constraints. Image you added has no nessesary information

Comment: Please provide more code and screenshots